# netbeans java code review plugin

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, review

Do you know of any java code review tool with a netbeans plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Netbeans, have a look at [SQE](http://java.net/projects/sqe/). It provides NB integration for:

- Code Defect Analysis: [FindBugs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/findbugs), [PMD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd), [CheckStyle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkstyle/), [Lint4j](http://www.jutils.com/)
- Metrics & Dependency Analysis: [Dependency Finder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/depfind)

If you're looking for a tool for peer-review of code, I'm not aware of one for NB. I have used [CodeStriker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codestriker) which is a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5031836.html) which discusses the pros and cons of three different plugins for code review. You will want to choose either [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) or [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/) does not appear to have NetBeans support.

Comment: Note: The URL for the article seems to have changed to: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-tools-that-make-java-code-review-painless-and-effective/